# HP ProLiant Gen9 - Mellanox ConnectX-2

Tags: networking, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, sfp

We have bought a cheap Mellanox ConnectX-2 NIC for 10G SFP+. Our server is a HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9. I've read that HP is very strict with the build in hardware. For example that iLO makes the fans to run at 100%.

So does anybody know if the HP Mellanox ConnectX-2 works with the mentioned server? It isn't listed in the quick specs manual, but the card is from HP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. I'd advise a more modern 10GbE card, though.

You'll need to download Mellanox drivers from HP in order to use the card.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :) Have you tested it already or why do you now,? Just out of interest :) What do you exaclty mean with "You'll need to download Mellanox drivers from HP in order to use the card." Do you mean we need the drivers for the OS? We tried the card already in another normal Desktop Gentoo machine and there it works out of the box :)